Centered Kernel Alignment and eigenspaces
In the paper I found, I read a paragraph that Centered Kernel Alignment shows the similarity between the top eigenspaces of kernels, before centering.
Centered Kernel Alignment is
$$\frac{HSIC(K, K')}{\sqrt{HSIC(K, K) HSIC(K', K')}}$$
while HSIC(K, K') is Hilbert-Schmidt Independce Criterion which is proportional to:
$$tr(KCK'C)$$
when C is a centering matrix.
What I felt was that due to a centering matrix, CKA measures the similarity of eigenspaces of centered kernels, instead of kernels before centering.
What did I miss? Can Centered Kernel Alignment show similarity between kernels before centering?
